# Fixed position scroll element flows offscreen when resizing browser window

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-position

I have a news website that has a sharing widget toolbar on the left side of every story, which includes facebook, twitter and other links. At the bottom, of the toolbar is an advertising spot 60x50px in which we market. The problem is that the sharing toolbar element is position fixed and so when you scroll it stays on the screen in the same spot, and when I resize the browser window, especially IE, sometimes the ad get cut off at the bottom. This is bad for maintaining this spot as an ad revenue builder for us and for the client.

Is there any CSS or javascript I can employ so that this doesn't happen?

[image: An example of the cut off fixed element]

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without a link, but I think you should change the absolute positioning from top:xxxpx to bottom:xxxpx - this will make sure it stays in the window upon resize...

Answer (score 0):

Use the below style:

```
.classname{
           position:absolute;
           top:10%; /*use the exact percentage of top screen you want to fix*/
           left:2%; /*use the exact percentage of left screen you want to fix*/ 
}
```